# Multiple application properties in struts2 and need to change property file in java based on somecondition?

Tags: java, struts2, resourcebundle

I am using

```
struts.custom.i18n.resources=file1,file2
```

**file1(ApplicationResources1.properties)**

```
enter.user = User name
```

**file2(ApplicationResources2.properties)**

```
enter.user = User name1
```

based on some condition  I need to switch over the file from file1 to file2 in action.?
I have used the following code...Both files are get loaded but i need to refer any of these files based on condition...

```
Struts.xml
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
    value="ApplicationResources2,ApplicationResources1" />

Test.java

if(condition){
    LocalizedTextUtil.clearDefaultResourceBundles();
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("ApplicationResources1.properties");
LocalizedTextUtil.setReloadBundles(true); 
}else{
    LocalizedTextUtil.clearDefaultResourceBundles();
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("ApplicationResources2.properties");
LocalizedTextUtil.setReloadBundles(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you properties files names are `ApplicationResources1.properties` and `ApplicationResources2.properties` then you need to use that names in `addDefaultResourceBundle` method of `LocalizedTextUtil`.

```
if(condition) {
  LocalizedTextUtil.clearDefaultResourceBundles();
  LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("ApplicationResources1");
  LocalizedTextUtil.setReloadBundles(true); 
}else {
  LocalizedTextUtil.clearDefaultResourceBundles();
  LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("ApplicationResources2");
  LocalizedTextUtil.setReloadBundles(true); 
}
```

Comment: @user989453: In your question there is `ApplicationResources1.properties` not `file1`.

Comment: yes..default should be ApplicationResources1.properties, then I need to change property file to ApplicationResources2.properties based on some condition

Comment: @user989453: Why then you are defining `struts.custom.i18n.resources` as `file1,file2`? So if you want to use `ApplicationResources1.properties` file then use `LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("ApplicationResources1");`.

Comment: Yes..absoultely.. I have like that only... but if I reload property file, I am getting label as enter.user only in jsp.. That means property file is not loaded ..right??

Comment: @user989453: So you have `LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("ApplicationResources1");` in your code and that is not working? Edit your question to show what have you tried.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr I have updated the question .. Have a look ..can you catch my point

Comment: @eswarpalani: Just use that names w/o `.properties` file extension.

Comment: I dont think thats issue since its working file if we dont use LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle();. both the properties files are loaded and picks the key from any one of file.. As per in struts.xml.. looks in ApplicationResources2 .if not goes to ApplicationResources1

Comment: @eswarpalani: For accepting an answer you do not need reputation points and for upvoting you need 15 points. So accept this answer.